# Clang integrated assembler and “unknown token in expression” during negate

Tags: c, assembly, clang, llvm, inline-assembly

We are using Clang in a default configuration. In the default configuration, Clang's Integrated Assembler is used (and not the system assembler, like GAS). I'm having trouble determining the exact problem (and fix) for:

```
make
...
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -Wall -fPIC -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Wno-tautological-compare -c integer.cpp
integer.cpp:542:2: error: unknown token in expression
        AS1(    neg             %1)
        ^
./cpu.h:220:17: note: expanded from macro 'AS1'
        #define AS1(x) GNU_AS1(x)
                       ^
./cpu.h:215:24: note: expanded from macro 'GNU_AS1'
        #define GNU_AS1(x) "\n\t" #x ";"
                              ^
<inline asm>:3:6: note: instantiated into assembly here
        neg %rcx;
            ^
```

The code in question is below.

I ***think*** the error above may be related to [Inline Assembly and Compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm). A simple `negq %1` did not work as expected:

```
integer.cpp:543:2: error: unknown token in expression
        AS1(    negq    %1)
        ^
./cpu.h:220:17: note: expanded from macro 'AS1'
        #define AS1(x) GNU_AS1(x)
                       ^
./cpu.h:215:24: note: expanded from macro 'GNU_AS1'
        #define GNU_AS1(x) "\n\t" #x ";"
                              ^
<inline asm>:3:7: note: instantiated into assembly here
        negq %rcx;
             ^
```

Since its Intel assembly, I also tried `negq [%1]`, `neg DWORD PTR [%1]` and `negq DWORD PTR [%1]` with no joy.

“unknown token in expression” appears to be a bogus message since the assembly instruction its complaining about does not seem to have a problem. So I suspect there is something else the Clang integrated assembler finds offensive.

What is the problem with the code?

---

Code causing the compile error:

```c
int Baseline_Add(size_t N, word *C, const word *A, const word *B)
{
    word result;
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
      ".intel_syntax;" "\n"
      AS1(  neg     %1)
      ASJ(  jz,     1, f)
      AS2(  mov     %0,[%3+8*%1])
      AS2(  add     %0,[%4+8*%1])
      AS2(  mov     [%2+8*%1],%0)
      ASL(0)
      AS2(  mov     %0,[%3+8*%1+8])
      AS2(  adc     %0,[%4+8*%1+8])
      AS2(  mov     [%2+8*%1+8],%0)
      AS2(  lea     %1,[%1+2])
      ASJ(  jrcxz,  1, f)
      AS2(  mov     %0,[%3+8*%1])
      AS2(  adc     %0,[%4+8*%1])
      AS2(  mov     [%2+8*%1],%0)
      ASJ(  jmp,    0, b)
      ASL(1)
      AS2(  mov     %0, 0)
      AS2(  adc     %0, %0)

      ".att_syntax;" "\n"
      : "=&r" (result), "+c" (N)
      : "r" (C+N), "r" (A+N), "r" (B+N)
      : "memory", "cc"
    );
    return (int)result;
}
```

Comment: Q: Why don't use use more "conventional" inline assembly syntax.  For example: http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm

Comment: @paulsm4: That link was in the question: “I think the error above may be related to [Inline Assembly and Compatibility]. A simple negq %1 did not work as expected:”

Comment: @paulsm4 - its existing code, and it was written by someone else. We are trying to add support for Clang's integrated assembler. I'm only trying to modify it so that its parsed by Clang's integrated assembler. I'm not trying to rewrite entire blocks (some are quite large).

Comment: Why did someone vote to close with the *"... include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*? I believe everything is included...

Comment: Whatever the heck you're trying to do, it looks like the code was taken directly from here: Crypto++ Library 5.6.1 API: http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/integer_8cpp_source.html.  "grep" through your source/headers for ASJ, AS1 and friends.

Comment: @paulsm4 - you are correct (I am a one of the Crypto++ maintainers). How will grepping the sources help me? What, exactly, am I looking for? How will it solve the *“unknown token in expression”* problem? (Please forgive my ignorance).

Comment: It looks like Clang's assembler doesn't like the `%` register prefix. You could try specifying `.att_syntax` for just that instruction and then use `negq %1`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue in the Integrated Assembler. One of the LLVM developers opened a PR after the question was asked on the CFE-dev mailing list. Also see [LLVM Bug 24232 - [X86] Inline assembly operands don't work with .intel_syntax](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24232).

I *think* that means Michael's comment could be a solution if we had the time and energy to rewrite blocks with 1000's of lines.