# How to use gcc or g++ in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk

I am using the `Crypto++` library in my Android NDK project. When I press the run button, the application works fine, and there are no issues, but when trying to build my `.apk` (build -> build APK) I get the exact error as [Clang integrated assembler and “unknown token in expression” during negate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577076/clang-integrated-assembler-and-unknown-token-in-expression-during-negate). As you can see there isn't a clear answer for the question. It seems like the problem is with the `Clang` (I am not really sure. I am just trying to use a `Crypto++`). I have tested using `Crypto++` in a windows application, and I used `QT+mingw`. It worked perfectly fine. Now, here are my questions:

1. Why doesn't it crash when I run my application but crashes when I try to build my `.apk`?
2. If the problem is with the `Clang` or `LLVM`, how can I use `gcc` (I used `gcc` in windows application). I tried to include `arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF','-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc'` ([How do I tell Android Studio to use GCC 4.9 with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243009/how-do-i-tell-android-studio-to-use-gcc-4-9-with-cmake)) but it said that `gcc` isn't supported anymore. Is there a way round to use `gcc` or `g++`?

Any other suggestions are welcomed too.

Comment: GCC is removed in NDK r18, Clang is default toolchain from NDK r13. Which NDK version you download?

Comment: I am using NDK 21.1.

Comment: May be you should download old release NDK r17, then try to set GCC 4.9

Comment: Trying to use an old NDK version seems like a dead end. What about when you need to update the NDK for some reason? It would be better to try to get the code to compile with the current NDK. For example, have you tried adding the `-fno-integrated-as` compiler flag?

Comment: @Michael Where should I add `-fno-integrated-as` in Android Studio?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeCmakeOptions

Comment: @Michael I added this code to the gradle file and it solved my problem:
`externalNativeBuild {cmake {cppFlags "-fno-integrated-as" }} `